# Moved Desktop directory and lost files. Can I undo the command

Tags: windows, command-line

I accidentally moved my Desktop directory, using the windows Command terminal, and every file on my desktop was removed. The command I used was `move C:/users/desktop`. I forgot to identify the 2nd location (where I wanted it to be moved), and it essentially just moved it somewhere else or deleted it entirely. Is there a way to undo this, or does anyone know where it was moved to?

Comment: What was you current working directory at the time? "Specify source only (will copy the file to current folder, keeping the same filename)" -- from the manual.

Comment: No.. not deleted.  Can you remember a portion of the names of at least one thing there?  If so.. from command.. go back to the root `cd c:\\ `  then `dir /s "*snippet*.*"` where "snippet" is the thing you are looking for.  You should see it's location show up in the list.